# git: are add, commit, and push concurrency-safe?

Tags: git, version-control, concurrency

I have a program that gathers information and checks the result into git.

I need to run the program several times, with each invocation writing to a separate top-level directory, e.g.

```
pgm --output=$REPO/a
pgm --output=$REPO/b
pgm --output=$REPO/c
```

Each invocation will modify the state under its output directory, add, commit, and push.

I would like to run these simultaneously.

```
pgm --output=$REPO/a &
pgm --output=$REPO/b &
pgm --output=$REPO/c &
```

Are there any concurrency issues I should be concerned with?

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29875267 goes somewhat in this direction

Answer (score 1):

Git has no problem doing things in parallel or in script.

If the git is in a middle of any operation it will automatically lock itself to reduce any option of data corruption.

So the answer to your question is simple: you can do it without any concerns.
Another related question is this:

[Is it safe if more git commands are run on the same repo in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459219/is-it-safe-if-more-git-commands-are-run-on-the-same-repo-in-parallel)